# Upload file via HTTP POST in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm backing up my hard drive on the cloud with a filehost. This filehost provides an API to do it but i just can't get it works on powershell.

On their API website (http://code.google.com/p/filecloud/wiki/Uploading) they claim that "We upload the file via HTTP POST request" so I use my trusty `POST_Request` function:

```
function POST_Request ($url,$parameters) {
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$contents = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(($client.UploadValues($url,$parameters) ))
return $contents
}
```

Since they website claim that they need 2 parameters to be sent in order to upload (a kind of id of my account and the file) i cannot use `UploadFile` in a `System.Net.WebClient` object.

In summary, my question is: How can I pass a parameter (the id) AND the file to be uploaded via POST? (maybe a trick with `UploadFile` will do it)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Normally those are put in a `NameValueCollection` IIRC and the NameValueCollection instance is passed as the "values" parameter to `UploadValues()`.  You're using `$parameters`.  Is that passed in to you or do you create it?  Either way, if it is a NameValueCollection, use the `Add` method to add the name/value pairs for the required parameters.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what ``$parameters`` is:
`$parameters = New-Object Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`;
`$parameters["Filedata"] = $file`;
`$parameters["id"]= $MyID`

Comment: After I call `POST_Request` I get the exception:
`Exception calling "UploadValues" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type."`

Comment: Have you set the content-type header on the request?  What is the server expecting in terms of file type?  Is it XML, plain text, JSON?  I think you'll need to set the content-type header appropriately (application/xml, text/plain, application/json).

Comment: Chris N  I've tried with the full path of the file.

@Keith Hill I'm not sure... but maybe it's JSON just like what the format of the response is by default. Sorry for not providing this detail, I'm not an expert but you can take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/filecloud/wiki/Uploading). Thanks!